# mount_null / mount --bind equivalent for OpenBSD

Tags: filesystems, mount, chroot, openbsd

What's the most efficient way of making an already mounted directory available within a chroot'ed environment (e.g. webserver)?

I know that Linux offers the `mount --bind` option and other BSD variants offer `mount_null` to allow mounting of a filesystem in a different location.

What is the best way of achieving this on OpenBSD?

I am aware some people are using NFS to achieve this functionality - is this really the best way of doing it? It seems like a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no bind mount variations in the OpenBSD base system. The `nullfs` filesystem was deleted some 15 years ago on account of being underused and of "demonstration code" quality.  The closest is the solution that you've mentioned yourself, i.e. to do a local NFS mount.

This is fairly easy to set up though and is commonly used to mount, e.g., the checked out ports CVS tree for building packages in the chroot set up by [`proot(1)`](https://man.openbsd.org/proot).

OpenBSD also has an `sshfs` port, and there's a `libfuse` in the base system, (see the `sysutils/sshfs-fuse` port), but I have no experience with these.